# How come this codes error? SQL Error code 1109: Unknown table 'o' in field list

Tags: mysql, sql

When i run this code, it gives me error. From this code, there's several task to do:
 (1) update tble customer by setting the address to '90 TYT' if c_id= 1 
(2) view order_no,status,c_id,item_total remarks. 
(3) if item_total 0, then update table order_status by setting remarks = 'UNAVAILABLE', else select order_no,status,item_total,remarks where status = 'waiting'.

Please help me fix the error. I'm new to SQL.

```
#drop procedure if exists usp_GetAnything;
delimiter //
create procedure usp_GetAnything()
begin

select c_id,lname,address,city
from customer;
update customer
set address = '90 TYT'
where c_id = 1;

select o.order_no,o.o_status,c.c_id,o.item_total,o.remarks
from customer c, order_status o
where c.c_id=o.c_id;

    if (o.item_total > 0) then 
    update order_status o
    set remarks = 'UNAVAILABLE'
    where order_no > '123';
    else  
    select order_no,o_status,item_total,remarks
    from order_status
    where o_status = 'waiting';

end if;

end
```

Comment: what dbms is it? MySQL?

Comment: yes. i'm using mysql. the codes gives the output. but it said , codes having an error 1109

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's failing on the line:

```
 if (o.item_total > 0)
```

`o` is unidentified outside of the previous `select` clause including all the selected variables.

In order to use the results that returned from the previous select you should `select ... INTO...`
(select the result arguments into declared local variables).

You can find **[here](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/an-introduction-to-stored-procedures-in-mysql-5--net-17843)** the following example:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE `proc_WHILE` (IN param1 INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE variable1, variable2 INT;
    SET variable1 = 0;

    WHILE variable1 < param1 DO
        INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (param1);
        SELECT COUNT(*) INTO variable2 FROM table1; 
        SET variable1 = variable1 + 1;
    END WHILE;
END //
```

You can see that `variable1` and `variable2` are declared in the beginning of the procedure and later on used with `select ... INTO ...`.

Comment: so, how it should be?

Comment: @F.A I showed you how - but I'm not going to write it for you. Now that you know what's wrong - fix it and try again, if you'll run into more issues you may post them on a separate question.